# MaxBlockSizeInMB does not exist my pyspark

Tags: pyspark, cluster-analysis

I was trying to build a clustering model using kmeans on a big data platform and I got this error, how to resolve it?

```
File "C:\Users\knwafor\run_scripts\bigdata.py", line 473, in <module>
    kmeans_model = kmeans.fit(data_with_pca)
  File "C:\Users\knwafor\run_scripts\runscripts_env\lib\site-packages\pyspark\ml\base.py", line 205, in fit
    return self._fit(dataset)
  File "C:\Users\knwafor\run_scripts\runscripts_env\lib\site-packages\pyspark\ml\wrapper.py", line 381, in _fit
    java_model = self._fit_java(dataset)
  File "C:\Users\knwafor\run_scripts\runscripts_env\lib\site-packages\pyspark\ml\wrapper.py", line 377, in _fit_java
    self._transfer_params_to_java()
  File "C:\Users\knwafor\run_scripts\runscripts_env\lib\site-packages\pyspark\ml\wrapper.py", line 174, in _transfer_params_to_java
    pair = self._make_java_param_pair(param, self._defaultParamMap[param])
  File "C:\Users\knwafor\run_scripts\runscripts_env\lib\site-packages\pyspark\ml\wrapper.py", line 158, in _make_java_param_pair
    java_param = self._java_obj.getParam(param.name)
  File "C:\Users\knwafor\run_scripts\runscripts_env\lib\site-packages\py4j\java_gateway.py", line 1322, in __call__
    return_value = get_return_value(
  File "C:\Users\knwafor\run_scripts\runscripts_env\lib\site-packages\pyspark\errors\exceptions\captured.py", line 169, in deco
    return f(*a, **kw)
  File "C:\Users\knwafor\run_scripts\runscripts_env\lib\site-packages\py4j\protocol.py", line 326, in get_return_value
    raise Py4JJavaError(
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o1468.getParam.
: java.util.NoSuchElementException: Param maxBlockSizeInMB does not exist.
        at org.apache.spark.ml.param.Params.$anonfun$getParam$2(params.scala:705)
        at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:189)
        at org.apache.spark.ml.param.Params.getParam(params.scala:705)
        at org.apache.spark.ml.param.Params.getParam$(params.scala:703)
        at org.apache.spark.ml.PipelineStage.getParam(Pipeline.scala:41)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor41.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
        at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
        at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
        at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
        at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
        at py4j.ClientServerConnection.waitForCommands(ClientServerConnection.java:182)
        at py4j.ClientServerConnection.run(ClientServerConnection.java:106)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

SUCCESS: The process with PID 13988 (child process of PID 17724) has been terminated.
SUCCESS: The process with PID 17724 (child process of PID 16860) has been terminated.
SUCCESS: The process with PID 16860 (child process of PID 7256) has been terminated.
```

Answer (score 0):

I later solved the problem by not using kmeans in pyspark but using a BisectingKMeans  algorithm which also gave me the clusters.